# How to check if a textbox has a value in it in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a form and in that form only allowed numbers and text. You can't have `.`, `,` or a space any where in the textbox.

These are the codes I've tried but they haven't worked.

```
if([".", ",", " "].indexOf(this.name) == 1) return true;
```

and

```
if(this.name == '.' || this.name == ',' || this.name == ' ') return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `this.name.includes('.')`

```
if (this.name.includes('.') || this.name.includes(',')) {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Vue - Vue isn't a form validator.

You need RegExp to test against the field's value. Assuming, as seems to be the case from your question, this is stored in `this.name`, you could do:

```
if (/[^\da-z]/i.test(this.name)) return false; //contains invalid input
```